# type keyword and not analyzed, any difference?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any difference between the "[keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/keyword.html)" field type and a field that uses "[not_analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html)" as analyzer in Elasticsearch? If there is one, when to use which?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As can be seen in the [breaking changes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html#_literal_string_literal_fields_replaced_by_literal_text_literal_literal_keyword_literal_fields) documentation, the `keyword` data type is a new data type coming up in ES 5. It aims at replacing the `string` fields with `"index": "not_analyzed"`.

So in ES 1.x and 2.x, this declaration

```
"field": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
}
```

is equivalent to this declaration in ES 5

```
"field": {
    "type": "keyword"
}
```

Similarly, the `text` data type will replace normal analyzed string fields, so in ES 1.x and 2.x, this declaration

```
"field": {
    "type": "string"
}
```

will equivalent to this declaration in ES 5

```
"field": {
    "type": "text"
}
```

Comment: Updated link for the breaking change: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html#_literal_string_literal_fields_replaced_by_literal_text_literal_literal_keyword_literal_fields

Comment: This is a brilliant explanation. It should have been explicitly mentioned by ES team.